# List is not set value to the control from presenter

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I'm trying to make a list of numericUpDown.value and, when I press the button, it sets a random value from the presenter; but, when I press the button nothing happen, I see the value change but I think it just replace the numeric control with a value instead of set value.

The view :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IForm1
{
    public List<decimal> _valueList { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       this._valueList = new List<decimal> { numericUpDown1.Value, numericUpDown2.Value, numericUpDown3.Value, numericUpDown4.Value, numericUpDown5.Value, numericUpDown6.Value };
    }

    public List<decimal> ValueList
    {
        get => _valueList; set => _valueList = value;
    }

    public event EventHandler ButtonClick;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonClick?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IForm1
{
    List<decimal> ValueList { get; set; }
    event EventHandler ButtonClick;
}
```

Presenter:

```
public class PresenterForm1
{
    private IForm1 _form1;

    public PresenterForm1(IForm1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;

        form1.ButtonClick += ButtonClick;
    }

    private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var random = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            _form1.ValueList[i] = random.Next(0, 10);
        }
    }
```

If I change the type to `List<NumericUpDown>` it works, but I think this is the wrong way:

```
foreach (var item in _form1.ValueList)
            {
                item.Value = random.Next(0, 99);
            }
```

Comment: I don't see any logic to assign the `NumericUpDown.Value` properties from your `ValueList`. However, I'm not familiar with the framework you're using. Is there some sort of data binding taking place here?

Comment: Im add NumericUpDown.value to list in constructor, and trying to set a new value from presenter `_form1.ValueList[i] = random.Next(0, 10);`, but i think im just replacing the current NumericUpDown instead of set a new value, also im can make a property from interface `decimal numericValue1{get;set;}` and work with it, but i have to many controls and try find a way to work with them all together